# Hacking up a podcast functionality with the Behringer XENYX 1202FX.

Tags: podcast

There are two pieces of functionality which I need from the Behringer XENYX 1202 FX.

1. Our podcast requires the use of Skype which means:

   - Skype-out must go to an input on the mixer
   - Skype-in should hear the other microphones but not the channel delerving Skype-out
2. We should have the ability to playing the Music to the output, while silencing the microphones from the mix.

Solving problem **1**  was rather simple all I had to do was make Skype-In `FX Out` and turn `FX` on the non-skype channels up (Skype channel turn `FX` Off). In this case I'm not using `FX In` at all.

The second one however is a little tricky. However, in [the manual](http://www.behringer.com/EN/downloads/pdf/1002FX_P0572_M_EN.pdf) I see the following:

> If you are recording a signal via the TAPE OUTPUT and wish to
>   listen to this simultaneously via the CD/TAPE INPUT, do not use the
>   CD/TAPE TO MIX switch. Doing this would create a feedback loop,
>   since the signal would be routed, via the main mix, back to tape via the
>   TAPE OUTPUT. To monitor the CD/TAPE INPUT, use the CD/TAPE TO CTRL
>   switch to assign the tape signal to the monitor(s) or headphones.
>   This will avoid the tape signal being routed to the TAPE OUTPUT.

I'm not sure I understand what they're saying. But, it sounds like it speaks to what I  want. Is there any way to accomplish my goal with the one 1202FX Mixer?

Comment: What is your music source? How many channels does your sound card have?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing a live web cast, not a recorded podcast.  Is that right?  Please provide more details of your setup.  How many participants?  Is there only one coming in via Skype?  Do you only have one computer or two (one for Skype and one for the cast)?

Comment: Did u have any luck? I do a podcast through Skype interviewing ppl and am getting this mixer. I want the ppl on the phone to hear the music in playing like the intro and music etc how can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure @Brian  I think I got working with 1202 FX, but ultimately I wanted a third bus for my cell phone or a Google Hangout, i ended up taking my hardware equipment up a huge notch and buying the X2442USB which I still run to this day with two Behringer USB DACs.

Comment: The X2442USB supports the mute button on the channels, has the option to send the channels to different buss pre-mix faders, and it supports Inserts which I now have hooked up to a 3632 compressor. In really has a ton of features at $320. I mounted it on a rack $100 rack, and it works great. http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001KJF0BE/ref=wms_ohs_product?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do the music as a post.. Then you can just add the music track in the background and make it 'Duck' behind the voices. And if you really need the music to keep the tempo of the podcast conversation, you can just have it play on another device (iPod) and have it mixed into just the headphones, but not record it at all.. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Duck' behind the voices. The important part of the functionality is that when the music is playing they can't hear the conversation we're having, until after the music is done playing.

Comment: "Duck" is generally an automated effect or track-attribute you can add on your DAW.. That will reduce the volume of a track when the other track has some sound, and will bring it back up when the other track has no sound. For example, in Garageband, it's the small up/down arrow in each track control.